# Retrieve publish information after MSDeployPublish

Tags: c#, web, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

In order to post a deploy notification to Rollbar I need to supply an environment. I have multiple publish profiles setup so that I can deploy to various development, test, and production environments. Is there an attribute or command I can use to get access to the profile / DeployIisAppPath from the publish profile?

I have the following target setup:

```
  <Target Name="NotifyRollbarOfDeploy" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <Exec Command="git log -1 --format=%%H" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" EchoOff="true" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)\..">
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitSHA" />
    </Exec>

    <Exec Command="git config user.email" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" EchoOff="true" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)\..">
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitEmail" />
    </Exec>

    <Exec Command="@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command &quot;(new-object net.webclient).UploadString('https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/deploy/', 'access_token=REDACTED&amp;environment=@(dev|test|production)&amp;revision=$(GitSHA)&amp;local_username=$(GitEmail)')&quot;" EchoOff="true" />
</Target>
```

How do I supply the value here for environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround for this was rather ugly. Rather than attempting to retrieve information from the target, I decided to fall back on Rollbar's suggested snippet for RollbarSharp. I needed to add three build configurations: dev, test, and prod in my case, and wire up my publish profiles to use those build configurations. Then I added web.config transforms for each build configuration that specified what the actual rollbar environment setting should be.

The transform portion looks like

```
  <appSettings>
    <add
      key="Rollbar.Environment"
      value="development"
      xdt:Transform="Replace"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
```